# Prevent to open a page on <a href="tel"> in IE

Tags: anchor

I am using

```
<a href="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```

in my website specifically for mobile but it is also shown in web browsers. Every browser didn't open a page while clicking on it instead of IE.

Any solution to prevent to open a page while clicking this number in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<a href="#" value="tel:123-456-7890">123-456-7890</a>
```

Than you could use a JS browser detection, see in this tread: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=210710
and then you can change the link in IE, and keep it the same in other browsers and mobile.

I use something like this in WordPress:

```
global $is_IE;
if(!$is_IE){  
?><a href="tel:555-555" >555-555</a><?php
} else 
{ ?>555-555<?php }
```

Comment: This technique is useless, because on mobile devices i couldn't achieve my goals using this technique. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Ahsan yes you can. JQuery works on mobile devices, too. Or (*warning* outside the box thinking ahead!) reverse that only remove the href on IE with JQuery.

Comment: @Mahmoud: Can you  please clarify with example?

Comment: Thanks Bogh, Actually I need a proper solution for this. This is also achievable by using conditional comments, but I need a proper way. I am using it in a static website. And i don't want to use javascript/jquery or other language to implement it. Thanks for your support.